SAP Commerce 2211 | SAP Backoffice Dashboard | css not loading for newly created custom dashboard widgets
I am working on SAP Backoffice dashboard customization. I have created couple of widgets with below structure -
backoffice\resources\widgets\dashboard\approvedproductsummarydashboard
  --- definition.xml
  --- approvedproductsummarydashboard.zul
  --- approvedproductsummarydashboard.scss
  --- scss
      --- support
          ---approvedproductsummarydashboard-variables.scss

approvedproductsummarydashboard.scss
@import "cockpitng-globals.scss";
@import "scss/support/approvedproductsummarydashboard-variables.scss";

after build using ant clean all, my scss got copied to backoffice extension at backoffice\resources\backoffice\generated\cockpitng\widgets\dashboard\approvedproductsummarydashboard location.
On the same location css approvedproductsummarydashboard.css file is also generated but when i am loading Backoffice, my css is not loading.
My issue is for none of my custom dashboard widget, css is loading in Backoffice despite its being generated in Backoffice extension.
